# Is there a jetpack compose issue in 1.1.0-beta3 when clicking outside a specific area (focus loss)?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I encounter a strange behavior when using the jetpack compose version 1.1.0-beta3 using the following simple code snippet (two buttons that trigger an adjustment/update of a text field accordingly):

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var text by remember { mutableStateOf("No text") }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .border(4.dp, Color.Red)
            ) {
                Text(text)
                Row {
                    TextButton({ text = "Test button on the left clicked" }) {
                        Text("Test 1")
                    }
                    TextButton({ text = "Test button on the right clicked" }) {
                        Text("Test 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it seems to work unless I click on the space outside of the two buttons (e.g. the complete screen occupied by the Column area (that fills the complete screen with the  `.fillMaxSize()` modifier)). I do NOT have this behavior with an older version e.g. [compose 1.0.5](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.0.5).

I should be able to change the version I am using, just wanted to know whether this is a known issue and yet to be reported or whether I am using this feature wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was probably a bugfix to the latest version of Compose that deals with how click events are propagated through the hierarchy for Columns (and other composables). In your code sample above, you are only using a Column. Any clicks on the column outside of the buttons will cause the click events to pass to the parent and it seems that the parent of the Column ends up obtaining the focus on these events. This prevents your buttons from regaining focus. To get around this, the Column needs to be placed inside a Surface which specifically is designed to prevent propagating the clicks. Try this:

```kotlin
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("No text") }

Surface(
     modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxSize()
          .border(4.dp, Color.Red)
) {
     Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
          Text(text)
          Row {
                TextButton({ text = "Test button on the left clicked" }) {
                     Text("Test 1")
                }
                TextButton({ text = "Test button on the right clicked" }) {
                     Text("Test 2")
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Check out the documentation on `Surface` as it describes this in detail:

[Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?hl=pt#Surface(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `Surface` in this case, as this bug is no longer reproduced in **1.1.0-beta4**